# Special cases where rearranging the order of a summation preserves value / divergence

Tags: summation

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1876828/how-to-change-the-order-of-summation) shows a special case of an infinite double sum where rearranging the order of summation preserves the value of the expression*

$$ \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=(i)}^{\infty}f(i,j)=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{j}f(i,j) $$

Or, written using an Iverson bracket

$$ \sum_{i \, \in \, \mathbb{N}} \sum_{j \, \in \, \mathbb{N}} [\,j \ge i\,] f(i,j) \;=\; \sum_{j \, \in \, \mathbb{N}} \sum_{i \, \in \, \mathbb{N}} [\,i \le j\,] f(i,j) $$

This suggests something interesting, namely that the expression $[i \le j] f(i,j)$ is special and can be summed in either order.

I'm not sure why that's the case, but I'm wondering if there are simple rules that can identify some of the expressions that are summable in either order or have the same divergence behavior in either order.

---

* One of the answers to the linked question justifies the identity by noting that both sides are equivalent to $$ \sum_{1 \le i \le j \le \infty} f(i,j) $$

It is not clear to me why this expression is well-defined unless the series is absolutely convergent or divergent.

Comment: By the way, a related question is [Which rearrangements do not change the sum?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1383730), which also links to an MO post. Also, sometimes one can do more with partial sums than treating the infinite sum as a whole, such as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1751536/21820).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not true.  For example, consider 
$$\eqalign{f(i,i) &= 1\cr f(i,i+1) &= -1\cr f(i,j) &= 0\ \text{ otherwise}\cr}$$  Then 
for all $i$, $\sum_{j=i}^\infty f(i,j) = 0$ so $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \sum_{j=i}^\infty f(i,j) = 0$$  On the other hand, 
$\sum_{i=1}^1 f(i,1)=1$ while $\sum_{i=1}^j f(i,j) = 0$ for $j \ge 2$, so $$\sum_{j=1}^\infty \sum_{i=1}^j f(i,j) = 1$$

Answer (score 2):

We can immediately exchange summations when the terms are non-negative, which is a special case of [MCT for real functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1573211/21820). We can also immediately exchange when $\sum_{i=1}^\infty |f(i,j)|$ converges for every $j$.

One might wonder whether exchanging the summation is always permissible when the following conditions all hold:

1. $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \sum_{j=i}^\infty f(i,j)$ converges.
2. $\sum_{j=1}^\infty \sum_{i=1}^j f(i,j)$ converges.
3. $f(i,j) \to 0$ as $i,j \to \infty$.

It is still not permissible, and here is an easy counter-example:

```
1 -1/2 -1/2    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  ..
   1/2  1/2 -1/3 -1/3 -1/3    0    0    0    0
             1/3  1/3  1/3 -1/4 -1/4 -1/4 -1/4
                            1/4  1/4  1/4  1/4
                                                ·.
```